# About convergence in $L_\text{loc}^1$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

I am confused by the expression below: $${||{u-u_m}||}_{L_\text{loc}^1(\Omega)}\to 0,\ \text{ as }\ m\to \infty.$$

Does it mean $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sup_{\Omega'\subset\subset\Omega}{||{u-u_m}||}_{L^1(\Omega')}=0,$$ or $$\lim_{m\to \infty}{||{u-u_m}||}_{L^1(\Omega')}=0,\ \forall \Omega'\subset\subset \Omega?$$
Which one is correct? Or neither is correct?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The first one doesn't make sense since $\sup_{\Omega'\subset\subset \Omega}\|u-u_m\|_{L^1(\Omega')}=\|u-u_n\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$ which might well be infinite. The second seems more reasonable.

Comment: I get it, thank you @LorenzoQ.

Comment: That is clear enough, (should be posted as an answer instead), thank you! @JanBohr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$-topology is equivalent to the second statement (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function#Lp,loc_is_a_complete_metric_space_for_all_p_%E2%89%A5_1)). I would never use the notation $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}}$ because there is no such norm. (At most collection of seminorms turning it into a Frechét-space, respectively a metric that defines the topology - again see the wikipedia article).